# HighCharts change zoom selectionMarkerFill color dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

Good day everyone. I got a question: can I change the zoom selection box color (selectionMarkerFill: rgba(69,114,167,0.25) - default value of the property) to any dynamically. I got an element on the page with Jquery UI resizable attached to it. so when I'm  resizing the element HighChart starts to draw a zoom blue rectangle. So I just want to make the color of the selection box to trasparent on the "start" event of the Resizable plugin and turn it back on on the "stop" event. or maybe just disable "zoomtype" property that way. Anyway I just wanna know is it possible to change the properties on the fly. Thanks!

Comment: make a fiddle of your code

Comment: it is kinda theoretical question. I think fiddle won't help in any case. (and there is pretty much code to paste). but I've created a dummy fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dMLdx/
Just try to select an area with mouse - you will see that the selection box is blue now. is it possible to change it to red for example by clicking the button on the fiddle?

Comment: I've checked the highcharts.js file and you can change the background color of rectangle. Line No. 155. Present color - rgba(69,114,167,0.25). Change it to whatever you want.

Comment: unfortunetely I need to change it dynamically. As Sebastian Bochan said it is not available without chart destroying.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the style on the fly using CSS. Dynamically add or remove a class to a parent element, then:

```
.your-dynamic-class .highcharts-selection-marker {
  fill: red!important;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unforutnately it is not avaialble, you need to destroy and create new chart or prepare your custom seleciton function, based on click.

Comment: could you please help with a custom click handler?